# delete token at the time of logout in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, mysqli, codeigniter-3

I am assigning the `user_id` to my session as soon as the user logs in, and I am giving a token to the user when he logs in, and I am storing it in the database just to keep the record. Now, I want to delete that token when the user clicks logout and for that,

**view**

```
<a href=" <?php base_url('user/logout') ?> ">logout</a>
```

**controller**

```
public function logout(){

$uid = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
$this->load->model('loginmodel');
$lid = $this->loginmodel->deltoken($uid);

if($lid){

  $this->session->unset_userdata('user_id');

  return redirect(user);

}else {
  echo "fail";
}
}
```

**model**

```
public function deltoken($uid)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("DELETE FROM user_auth WHERE id = '$uid'");
    return TRUE;
}
```

but in the database record belonging to that particular id is not getting deleted. what am i doing wrong here?
Thank you for your suggestions

Comment: what is the error you got?

Comment: no error, but it doesnt delete the row

Comment: you want to delete whole row or token field only

Comment: i want to delete whole row

Comment: Try with this Code : `public function deltoken($uid)
{
    $this->db->where('id' ,$uid);
    $this->db->delete('user_auth');
    if ( $this->db->affected_rows() )
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    
}`

Comment: still not deleting the row

Comment: make sure you get the user id in deltoken method

Comment: how should i do that?

Comment: do this `public function deltoken($uid)
{
    echo $uid;die;
      
}`  or use session user_id directly in the deltoken  method

Comment: same thing is happening, i think deltoken is not getting called only

Comment: you can check for the token in your method with session

Comment: check for white spaces.... Can you echo $query result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*You are missing `echo` in your link, should be like this :*

```
<a href=" <?php echo site_url('user/logout') ?> ">logout</a>
```

*Your model `deltoken` method should be like this :*

```
public function deltoken($uid)
{
    $uid  = ! empty($uid) ? $uid : $this->session->user_data('user_id');
    $this->db->where('id' ,$uid);
    $this->db->delete('user_auth');
    if ( $this->db->affected_rows() )
    {
      return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
      return FALSE;
    } 
}
```

Comment: your model should be like this

Comment: when i go http://localhost/ci/index.php/user/logout , the method works but when i click on "logout" link in my view it doesnt

Comment: use site_url instead of base_url if u have not removed your index page in config.php

Comment: still doesnt work. In my config.php,    $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci/'; $config['index_page'] = 'index.php';

Comment: you are missing echo in your link should be like this :  `<a href=" <?php echo site_url('user/logout') ?> ">logout</a>`